# Django - value of form field as default value of another form field

Tags: django

I would like to fill my form field (url) and use that url as default value in my next form field (in another view). I am not able to switch views and take that form value. Any advices? Here are my files:

views.py

```
def subcategory(request, category_name_slug, subcategory_name_slug):
    context = {}
    form = SiteAddForm()
    context['form'] = form
    try:
        category = Category.objects.get(slug=category_name_slug)
        subcategory = SubCategory.objects.filter(category=category
                                             ).get(slug=subcategory_name_slug)
        sites = Site.objects.filter(subcategory=subcategory)
        context['subcategory'] = subcategory
        context['sites'] = sites
    except (SubCategory.DoesNotExist, Category.DoesNotExist):
        raise Http404("Nie ma takiej strony")
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SiteAddForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            siteurl = form.cleaned_data['url']
            context['siteurl'] = siteurl
            return render(request, 'mainapp/add_site.html', context)
return render(request, 'mainapp/subcategory.html', context)

def add_site(request, category_name_slug, subcategory_name_slug):
context = {}
forms = SiteAddFormA()
context['form'] = forms

return render(request, 'mainapp/add_site.html', context)
```

forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from mainapp.models import Site


class SiteAddForm(forms.Form):

    url = forms.URLField(label='Url')


class SiteAddFormA(forms.ModelForm):
    url = forms.URLField(max_length=200, help_text='Please enter the URL of     the page.')

class Meta:
    model = Site
    fields = ('url', 'name', 'description',)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
url(r'^category/(?P<category_name_slug>[\w\-]+)/$', views.category,
    name='category'),
url(r'^category/(?P<category_name_slug>[\w\-]+)/(?P<subcategory_name_slug>[\w\-]+)/$',
    views.subcategory,
    name='subcategory'),
url(r'^category/(?P<category_name_slug>[\w\-]+)/(?P<subcategory_name_slug>[\w\-]+)/(?P<id>[\w\-]+)/$',
    views.site,
    name='site'),
url(r'^category/(?P<category_name_slug>[\w\-]+)/(?P<subcategory_name_slug>[\w\-]+)/add_site/$',
    views.add_site,
    name='add_site'),
```

]

models.py:

```
class Site(models.Model):
category = models.ForeignKey('Category')
subcategory = ChainedForeignKey(
    'Subcategory',
    chained_field='category',
    chained_model_field='category',
    show_all=False,
    auto_choose=True)
name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
description = models.TextField()
keywords = MyTextField()
date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
url = models.URLField()

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

Comment: You can do it with django sessions, one the first view you save the session and on the second view you get that same session and put it as an initial value. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/sessions/

Comment: is the first form in subcategory view and then next form is add_site view? if so, you don't save url you put in first form. If you just want to make a user select url based on sites in category(you are sending those data in context),  how about just showing first form and second form at the same template? just you can show first form(it doesn't have to be form because it doesn't need to submit data to server with HTTP Post) and then hide this and show second form with url which is wrriten in first form. This is my idea. if you did that for validation, it seems fine to do that with js in front

Comment: I am trying to take mike's advice but I don't know how can I use variable from first form as initial value in second form. I hid my first form, show second (i used simple {% if not form1 %} in my template file) but what should i do next? Ok. I solved it. I used initial={'url': siteurl} . It works fine I think.